# Generating LinqToEntities Where statement depending on the user selection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, optimization

I have user-interface where user can select grid column (like age) and operator (lesser than, equals or greater than) for that column.

Grid data is then filtered according to the selection.

I have a following classes that are deserialized from the JSON that is coming from the client.

```
/// <summary>
/// Filter for reducing grid results
/// </summary>
public class Filter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the column
    /// </summary>
    public string name;

    public string value;

    public int @operator { private get; set; }

    public Operator Operator()
    {
        return (Operator) @operator;
    }
}

public enum Operator
{
    None = -1,
    LesserThan = 0,
    Equals = 1,
    GreaterThan = 2
}
```

Due to the nature dynamically adding new columns for filtering I would like to create generic solution for accessing the data.

I would like avoid having huge amount if/switch statements like

```
switch(columnName)
{
    case "age":
    {
        if(operator == Operator.LesserThan)
        {
             query = entities.Where(o => o.Age < age);
        }
        else if (operator == Operator.GreaterThan)
        {
             query = entities.Where(o => o.Age > age);
        }
        etc.

        break;
    }
    etc.
}
```

Any ideas how to create more generic solution for the problem?

**Update**
It seems that there many ways to accomplish cleaner solution than one billion if statements. Now I just need to compare different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to create the query dynamically

Edit:

An example for Dynamic LINQ query would look like this, assuming that the column names in the grid are the same as the field names in the entity:

```
string queryString;
queryString = columnName;
if(operator == Operator.LesserThan)
{
  queryString += " < ";
}
else if (operator == Operator.GreaterThan)
{
  queryString += " > ";
}
etc.
queryString += age.ToString();  // Or use bind variables, haven't tried that myself in dynamic LINQ

query = entites.Where(queryString);
```

Comment: Could you share a sample that would be applicable to the OP's use case, in order to make your answer more descriptive and complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to dynamically build up linq queries based on whatever youi want. That will help you build up a linq expression easily. As for the ugly switch that would grow and grow over time, I would suggest perhaps if "name" always related to a property in your linq expression (e.g. "age" --> .Age), then you should be able to get that with some reflection code - so you check if "name" does relate to a property of the same name, and if so build a filter for it..

HTH

Comment: Very good! I think this is exactly what I need. Now I just have to check the other answer regarding the Dynamic LINQ and decide which one is more suitable. I'll pick then the winning answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the Where method a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression object that you compose from your input.  Here is an example of how to compose predicate expressions for use with EF or Linq2Sql:
[Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ESQL instead of just LINQ:

```
Context.Entities
    .Where("it.Age > @Age", new[] { new ObjectParameter("Age", age } );
```

you can easily generate string representation for your criteria based on the filter you have.

Here is the [full reference to ESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx) should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection code such as :

```
String columName; //your dynamic columnName

if(operator == Operator.LesserThan)
        {
             query = entities.Where(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(columName).GetValue(o, null) <columName);
        }
        else if (operator == Operator.GreaterThan)
        {
            etc.
        }
```

Comment: I think it's nice and simple.